# Why is Allah just to us even if he punished all of us?

Tags: hadith, tafseer

The following is a part of a hadith:

> If God Almighty tormented the people of His heavens and the people of His land, He would have tormented them not unjust to them

- [Link to hadith](http://hadith.islam-db.com/single-book/52/%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%AF-%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%8A/18213/615), but I found the translation [here](https://motamiiz.com/trend/%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%AB%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%B1/)
- Allah knows that we humans are weak; so it should be unjust for him to torment all of his creatures. but what about creatures that can't disobey him (angels)?

---

My conclusion:

The fact that Allah **appreciates our efforts to obey him**, **appreciates that it isn't satisfying for us to obey Him all of the time** and **forgives us** is **mercy**, while **justice** is kind of robotic (you disobey, you get punished) and is not what we want, so thanks Allah for Your mercy.

Comment: Please, do mention the reference to this Hadith.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know how to reference a hadith, but I added a link for it

Comment: The page you gave link to is in Arabic. Many people do not understand Arabic, as I believe, as this site is for English speakers. Is this your own translation?

Comment: @Muslim, I found the translation [here](https://motamiiz.com/trend/%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%AB%D9%84%D8%A9-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%B1/)

Comment: do not add comments into your post to respond the answerers. There is comments section under each answer post. Leave your comments there.

Comment: You're right. But when I mention someone, the "@Someone" gets deleted from the comment!

Answer (score 1):

Torment is a bad translation. The hadith says:

> Were Allah to punish everyone in the heavens and in the earth, He would do so without being unjust to them. And were He to show mercy to them, His mercy would be much better than their actions merited.

That is because all of us have committed sins that would deserve the punishment.

But, the only reason Allah forgives and allows us to get rewarded for frankly little to no effort is that He is Merciful and Loving.

None of us deserve the reward. It is only given from His mercy.

Allah says in the Quran:

> And your Lord is the Forgiving, full of mercy. If He were to impose blame upon them for what they earned, He would have hastened for them the punishment. Rather, for them is an appointment from which they will never find an escape. (18:58)

Allah says: ⟪If He were to impose blame upon them for what they earned, He would have hastened for them the punishment.⟫ Meaning: If he truly was to hold people to account for what their actions deserve, they would all fall into punishment.

However, He says: ⟪Rather, for them is an appointment from which they will never find an escape.⟫ Meaning: Because of His mercy, He lets them go until the Day of Judgement. Then, He holds to account those He wishes and forgives the believers.

The Prophet (SAW) said:

> "Do good deeds properly, sincerely and moderately, and receive good news because one's good deeds will not make him enter Paradise." They asked, "Even you, O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)?" He said, "Even I, unless and until Allah bestows His pardon and Mercy on me." ([Sahih Bukhari 6467](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6467))

Comment: What about angels? didn't they subject all of their time and energy to obey? and justice is that they end up in hell even though they did their best to obey him? unless you mean **temporarily** going to hell...

Comment: @AZeed In reality, even the angels could deserve punishment. Who knows if they did their best to obey Him. If they did the best to obey Him, they would be robots, but angels too are people of free will. Their only limitation is their inability to disobey. But, Allah is Merciful and Forgiving and doesn't hold people to the full standard of justice.

Comment: If Allah created us mentally and physically incapable of being obedient all of the time, then why is justice that he punishes us indefinitely?

Comment: @AZeed Who said we are incapable. Rather, we are entirely capable. We just don't do it because we don't like to and we prefer to do what is easier. That is not incapability but choice.

Comment: Can you prove that it is possible for anyone to be able to live following a guide all of the time?

Comment: @AZeed Not sure what you want as proof. The fact that there is no physical barrier to doing so is very clear. It is simply that we do not do so because it is hard and we do not want to do what is hard.